# wijmo FlexGrid implementation with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, wijmo, msflexgrid

Can we implement wijmo FlexGrid with Angularjs.I want to implement all FlexGrid properties like filtering, paging, sorting column. Any pointers will help.

Comment: Yes, there are several AngularJS samples for the Wijmo FlexGrid.  I'd suggest you start by looking at the samples, http://wijmo.com/5#demos.

Answer (score 0):

We do ship Angular 1.x and 2.0 directives with Wijmo, so you don't have to implement those directives yourself.

Here is some sample markup using the "wj-flex-grid" directive defined in the wijmo.angular.js file:

```
   <wj-flex-grid items-source="data" style="height: 150px;margin-top:10px" control="flex">
        <wj-flex-grid-column header="Country" binding="country"></wj-flex-grid-column>
        <wj-flex-grid-column header="Sales" binding="sales"></wj-flex-grid-column>
        <wj-flex-grid-column header="Expenses" binding="expenses"></wj-flex-grid-column>
        <wj-flex-grid-column header="Downloads" binding="downloads"></wj-flex-grid-column>
    </wj-flex-grid>
```

You can see this sample in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wijmo5/QNb9X/